# Why does Sitecore 8 require SQL 2012 for the SQL shared session state database?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I realise that you don't have to use MSSQL for the shared session state database - you can use MongoDB or InProc, but the question is why is SQL **2012** specifically required rather than SQL 2008.

** Update **

https://doc.sitecore.net/en/Products/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/xDB_configuration/Walkthrough_Configuring_a_private_session_state_database_using_the_SQL_Server_provider.aspx

> To deploy the SQL Server session database:
>
> Start Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012 or later. Important
>   If you are using SQL Server 2008, you first need to download Microsoft
>   SQL Server Management Studio 2012 Express before you can deploy the
>   Session database. Connect to the server node that you want to install
>   the Session database on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a requirement to use SQL Server 2012 specifically, you should be able to use 2008 R2 as well as long as you are using SQL Management Studio 2012 to deploy and manage the database. This is mentioned in the [configuration documents](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/xdb_configuration/walkthrough_configure_a_shared_session_state_database_using_the_sql_server_provider):

> If you are using SQL Server 2008, you first need to download Microsoft
>   SQL Server Management Studio 2012 Express before you can deploy the
>   Session database.

The [compatibility matrix](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164) also indicates that Sitecore 8 is compatible with SQL Server 2008 R2 and upward.

Comment: Any idea why 2012 management studio is required to attach the db if it is compatible with 2008 ?